# Calling Methods

Tags: java, methods

This is probably a really stupid question, but I'm having problems calling methods in java. For my computer science class I am instructed to write a single program with multiple methods. In one method I am to prompt the user to enter an integer, return that integer and store it in a variable. The next method is to be passed the integer from the previous method and return true if the integer is odd and false if it is not.

My problem is this, when I try to call the second method from the main method, I get an error message saying "cannot find symbol. symbol number" I'm sure it has something to do with the scope of the variable only existing within the getInput method, but I don't know how to get the program to print the value from my second method if it won't recognize my variable from the first method.

Here's what I have come up with so far. (You can disregard the method named printBanner, that one works, I'm just having trouble with the next two, getInput and isOdd)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MethodlabPractice {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    printBanner();
    getInput();
    isOdd(number);
  } // end main

    public static void printBanner () {
     for (int count = 0; count != 10; count++)
        System.out.println("Beth Tanner");
    } // end printBanner

    public static int getInput() {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Please enter an integer:");
          int number = input.nextInt();
          System.out.println(number);

          return number;
    } // end getInput

    public static boolean isOdd(int number) {
      boolean odd = number % 2 != 0;

    return odd;
    } // end isOdd
}// end class
```

Comment: Its always easier to answer a question about an exception if you post the stacktrace.

Comment: @Deadron This should actually be a compiler error, hence no stack trace. It still will give an error message, though, which OP should post in full.

Comment: Downvote was mean. We were all beginners once.

Comment: Agree with NickJ.  While no errors were posted, the explanation was good and the code is pretty clear -- especially for a beginner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't defined the variable `number` within the scope of the `main` method.

```
int number = getInput();
isOdd(number);
```

Comment: Well I feel dumb, that's easy enough. Thanks!

Comment: You should also accept his answer. Another alternative is `isOdd(getInput())`.

Comment: This solved the problem I was having, but now instead of using the value stored in number for the isOdd method, it asks for another integer before printing true or false. How can I make sure it just used the value I entered when prompted the first time rather than being prompted again?

Comment: There's something funny going on there - you're not calling `getInput` twice by any chance?

Comment: @Reimeus not intentionally, but I may be.

Answer (score 4):

getInput returns int, save it and then pass it

```
int number = getInput();
isOdd(number);
```

instead what you are trying to do is

```
getInput();
isOdd(number);  // passing number, but number is not defined
```

Or you can do:

```
isOdd(getInput());
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the argument `number` to `isOdd()` method inside your `main` method. But `number` must be declared before it can be passed.